# Snaplogic querying two sources and joining data together

Tags: snaplogic

I am trying to build a Pipeline which queries out my Sales records (as one Read activity)
Now in this Sales schema there are fields that reference a People table however its not a direct connection as there is a Many-to-Many relationship.

So what I need to do is query my PeopleToSales table for all related records and populate them in a flat structure in my subsequent JSON object.

How can I built two objects together and join them based on Sales ID? Also in the event there are multiple matches how can I choose the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You can read both the Sales records and the PeopleToSales table and then use the **Join** snap to merge the relevant documents based on whatever ID that defines the relation between them.

After that, you can use the **Group By Fields** snap to group the documents based on Sales ID.

You can add the Sales ID field (say - `$sales_id`) in the **Fields** list in the settings and it will group documents based on the Sales ID.

Also, when using the **Group By Fields** snap, you first have to sort the documents based on the keys. So, use a **Sort** snap before the **Group By Fields** snap.

As far as getting the first object is concerned, after the group-by, you can just get the 0th element of the list (say `group[0]`).

Please refer to - [SnapLogic Docs - Group By Fields](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1439014/Group+By+Fields)